# regex to match any words with spaces with superscript

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, pattern-matching, schema

Here is the superscript `heyʰ howʱ`I am looking for a regular expression that matches any words that are seperated by spaces and have a superscript. I am setting this as a `<xs:restriction>` in the schema file. I am really new to regex to come up but here is my attempt:

```
<xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
    <xs:pattern value='(\w)\s+(\w)'/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you clarified that you are talking about types for attributes, the only way superscripts could appear at all is if you use some of the very few literal superscript characters provided by Unicode: U+00B2, U+00B3, U+00B9, U+2070, U+2071, U+2074 - U+207F.  There are a few others that for some purposes might be construed as superscripts.  As I originally wrote, you can match those in a regex via a character class; it would look something like this:

```
<xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
  <xs:pattern value='\S+[&#xb2;&#xb3;&#xb9;&#x2070;&#x2071;&#x2074;-&#x207f;]+ +\S+[&#xb2;&#xb3;&#xb9;&#x2070;&#x2071;&#x2074;-&#x207f;]+'/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Pretty ugly.

Comment: `hey how` is in a attribute in xml so I cannot add `hey<xhtml:sup>h</xhtml:sup> how<xhtml:sup>n</xhtml:sup>` a new tag in there. Have to add a regex

Comment: As I said, in that case you can match the superscript characters via a character class.  I updated my answer to demonstrate.